# JQuery: How to properly indent a string when looping over dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code is here http://jsfiddle.net/Ea7hd/1/

Basically my output needs to match the indentation of the html elements as they appear in the textarea.

The problem is that when I am looping through all the elements in the textarea I have no way of adding proper indentation because the I have no way of setting where one element is in relation to its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<div>` with `padding-left`: http://jsfiddle.net/Ea7hd/5/.

Identation, padding and margin are styles, so you should achieve them trough CSS, so you shouldn't do it adding `&nbsp;`.